# How much nutrients does over-watering remove?

Tags: watering, containers, nutrients

I've encountered the following statement(no source but multiple times):

> When excess water drains off a container, it removes nutrients from the soil.

Is that true? In the practical sense instead of "there's a N atom in there". Does draining the water and discarding it compare to what the plant "steals"?

Comment: It is obviously true, but to put a figure on it would make this an opinion based question.  Who measures precisely how much water drains off as compared to evaporation as compared to how much is poured on the soil.

Comment: @RohitGupta scientists, I hope. Also my question is about the remaining nutrients in the soil. Which probably makes it even more impossible to answer.

Comment: Depends if the nutrients are soluble. Look up “nutrient leaching”